# Loader lock (regsvr32 R6033 error) with managed C++ dll

Tags: c++, clr, managed

I have a C++ dll which implements several COM interfaces, that I'm trying to migrate to managed C++.  I set the /clr compiler flag and changed the Runtime Library property from /MT to /MD to avoid the conflict between these two flags, but that's all I've changed.  When it attempts to register the dll during the build process, I get the following error:

*R6033 - Attempt to use MSIL code from this assembly during native code initialization
This indicates a bug in your application. It is most likely the result of calling an MSIL-compiled (/clr) function from a native constructor or from DllMain.*

I read about Loader Lock and can't figure it out - I have not added a single call to any managed code.  Here's the entire body of the DllMain procedure:

[Edit - per comment below, I added #pragma unmanaged to the top of the cpp file with no improvement.  The Module init is all code contained in the ATL libraries from what I can tell.]

```
extern "C"
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    lpReserved;
    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        _Module.Init(ObjectMap, hInstance, &MYGUID);
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hInstance);
    }
    else if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
        _Module.Term();
    return TRUE;    // ok
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the /clr compiler flag only to the files that use managed code and not for the whole project.

This is what the Visual Studio "Wizard" does, here is how I've tested:

- Create a Visual C++ ATL Project
- Added a ATL Simple Object, in order to have a COM interface (Project->Add Class)
- Added a CLR Component Class. The Wizard prompted me with "You are adding a CLR component to a native project. Your project will be converted to have Common Language Runtime support."
- Compile project, compiles fine and registers fine.
- Checked the project settings -> "No Common Language Runtime support"
- Checked the clrcomponennt.cpp settings -> "Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)"
- Opened the dll in OleView -> COM interface was present
- Opened the dll in Red Gate's .NET Reflector -> clrcomponent was present

Comment: Thanks, that got it.  I didn't realize I could set the flag on a file-by-file basis - switching the file with the DLL init code to non-/clr fixed, while leaving the rest of the project with the /clr switch on.

Answer (score 0):

Using /clr flag has made your methods managed (ie. they are being compiled down to MSIL), but you're calling them for DllMain which -isn't- managed. Unfortunately, that's about as far as my limited knowledge can take it.

Comment: Yeah that would make sense...I added #pragma unmanaged to the top of the file but it didn't help.